# Laravel Envoyer - Testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge, envoyer.io

I just signed up for Laravel Envoyer since my Laravel application has grown a bit (1 Application Server, 2 Queue Worker Servers, a Logging Server, etc).

Locally, I develop in Laravel's `homestead` environment.

I plan to have a set of Staging servers and a set of Productions servers.

The idea is, I wanted to be able to push to all the servers (in a particular environment) at once, at the very least, run some important environmental tests on each box.  This is because I need to ensure that certain .env variables exist and are set correctly.

However, from what I have read, it seems that tests are generally not run on your one's live servers.  In fact, Envoyer by default does `composer install --no-dev`, which would exclude `phpunit` entirely.

Now, I could move `phpunit` out of the `require-dev` section of my `composer.json` and into the main dependency list, but I just wanted to confirm that there isn't a better approach or a preferred practice in this sort of multi-server deployment?

Answer (score 3):

There is **Install "Dev" Composer Dependencies** option at:

*Project settings -> source control* tab.

Not sure if this option existed at the time you've asked the question.

[image]